# 하나 둘씩’s meaning

Tags: grammar

What does 하나 둘씩 mean. 하나씩 means one at a time. 둘씩 means two at a time. But I don’t understand what 하나 둘씩 is. I just checked other websites. Some say it means “one by two”. But I don’t understand what “one by two” means.

Could someone give some explanation of this word ? Please.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

하나둘씩 (= 한둘씩) means *(about) one or two at a time* and *in ones and twos*.

하나둘씩 consists of 하나둘 and -씩.

> 하나둘 (= [한둘](https://krdict.korean.go.kr/eng/dicSearch/SearchView?nation=eng&ParaWordNo=72435)): 하나나 둘쯤 되는 수 (a number that is about one or two)
>
> -씩: ‘그 수량이나 크기로 나뉘거나 되풀이됨’의 뜻을 더하는 접미사. (a suffix used to add the meaning of being divided or repeated by that number or size.)

---

You should *not* use 하나둘씩 to mention the number of times *but* that of other things or that of people. Examples are the following:

- 시민이 **하나둘씩** 버스에서 내렸다.
- 꽃잎이 **하나둘씩** 떨어지기 시작했습니다.
- 놀이터에 어린이들이 **하나둘씩** 모여들었습니다.